# Comparing columns with multiple conditions

Tags: vba, excel

---

I have been trying to compare two columns with multiple conditions.

1. In column 'A' a two digit value is present which leads to a seven digit value in column 'B' and so on wherever column 'A' has two digits.
2. In column 'A' a three digit value is present which leads to a eight digit value in column 'B' and so on wherever column 'B' has three digits.
3. Row 4 and 5 are blanks. (No. and position of row can be anything and anywhere).
4. B7 and B8 are blank (This also can be anywhere in column 'B').
5. A12 is blank (This too can be anywhere in the Column'A').
6. B11 has Zero but A11 has value (Position is not fixed it can be anywhere) if so just pass the value (it can be the case no issues).

Now with all of the above Criterion the following a macro must perform.

I want to validate whether 'B2' and 'B3' start with 45 and 57 Resp as given in 'A2' and 'A3' and has seven digits.

And 'B7' and 'B8' start with 234 and 567 Resp as given in 'B7' and 'B8' and has eight digits.

If whole row is blank (As row4 and row5) delete entire row.

If any cell in column 'A' has value and subsequent cell is blank (As in  B9 and B10) it must show a msgbox "Column 'B' must be reviewed "

If any cell in column 'B' has value and preceding cell is blank (As in  A12) it must show a msgbox "Column 'A' must be reviewed "

And here is the image:-

[image]
After all, if any of the criteria aren't met, show a msgbox "the following rows has issues..."

The issues i am facing are :-
1.As in Row11 cell 'B11 ' has zero so if i run the code it consider this as error which should not be the case. 2. for B9 and B10 as they are blank it is not showing any error but it should 3. And for A12 too which is blank but B12 has value it must show error

I have written or gathered this code:-

```
Sub Comparing()
    Range("A:B").Select

    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

    ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd

    ActiveSheet.Range("B:B").EntireColumn.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>0", Operator:=xlAnd

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim strA As String, strB As String, str As String
    Dim NotMatched As Boolean

    lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = Range("B2:B" & lr)
    str = "The following cells don't match." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

    For Each cell In rng
        If cell <> "" Then
            n = Len(cell.Offset(0, -1))

            If n > 0 Then
                strA = cell.Offset(0, -1).Text
                strB = Left(cell, n)

                If strA <> strB Then
                    NotMatched = True
                    str = str & cell.Offset(0, -1).Address(0, 0) & " : " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & vbTab & cell.Address(0, 0) & " : " & cell.Value & vbNewLine
                End If

            Else
                str = str & cell.Offset(0, -1).Address(0, 0) & " : " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value & vbTab & cell.Address(0, 0) & " : " & cell.Value & vbNewLine
            End If

        End If

        n = 0
        strA = ""
        strB = ""

    Next cell

    If NotMatched Then
        MsgBox str, vbInformation
        Exit Sub
    Else
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? - it's much easier if you tell us rather than we have to guess...

Comment: That indentation is going to give me a headache, considering all of your scenarios. Could you please review your code format? Also, could you please come to us with *specific* question? **What is wrong with your code?**

Comment: Well thanks for your super fast reply :-)     Following things are the issues i a m facing :- 1.As in Row11 cell 'B11 ' has zero so if i run the code it consider this as error which should not be the case.
2. for B9 and B10 as they are blank it is not showing any error but it should
3. And for A12 too which is blank but B12 has value it must show error

Comment: Does this answer your questions @Tim Williams and @ dwirony ?

Comment: I have edited the issues i faced and the code format doesn't require any changes it seems to me.

Comment: Yeah well that's because someone went in and bothered to edit it for you. I hope your code looks like this and not like what you had before.

Comment: @Mat'sMug That would be me reformatting the code. Of course, that was *just before* I noticed your comment about Rubberduck.

Answer (score 2):

This code lines will delete all rows where either of the cells in a row are blank

```
Range("A:B").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
```

---

I didn't add an `AutoFilter` because it wasn't part of the question.  To simplify the logic I clearly defined `cellA` and `cellB`,  I also define a flag that trigger the message to be added, if any of the conditions were not met.

```
Sub Comparing_Refactored()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim cellA As Range, cellB As Range
    Dim x As Long

    Dim bFlag As Boolean
    Dim msg As String

    With ActiveSheet
        For x = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Rows(x)) = 0 Then .Rows(x).Delete
        Next

        For Each cellA In .Range("B2", .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Offset(0, -1)
            bFlag = False
            Set cellB = cellA.Offset(0, 1)
            If cellA.Value = 0 AND cellB.Value = 0 Then
                'Do Nothing
            ElseIf cellA.Value = "" Or cellB.Value = "" Then
                bFlag = True
            ElseIf cellA.Value Like "##" And Not cellB.Value Like cellA.Value & "#####" Then
                bFlag = True
            ElseIf cellA.Value Like "###" And Not cellB.Value Like cellA.Value & "#####" Then bFlag = True
                bFlag = True
            End If

            If bFlag Then
                msg = msg & cellA.Address(False, False) & " : " & cellA.Value & vbTab & cellB.Address(False, False) & " : " & cellB.Value & vbNewLine
            End If
        Next

    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    If Len(msg) > 0 Then MsgBox msg, vbInformation, "Errors Found"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Thomas Inzina this is exactly what i was searching for except one thing if any of the cells in the column 'B' has zero and the preceding cell (i.e. cell in column 'A') has value it must pass this scenario but the macro is considering this also as an error. Please help me out !